How to project a 3D sdf to the 2D plane and get the 2D expression of the sdf?
For a shape S, $\sigma S$ is the boundary of the shape S, SDF expression:
$$
sdf(x) = \left\{  
             \begin{array}{**lr**}  
             -|distance(x, \sigma S)|, x \in S&   \\  
             0, x \in \sigma S & \\
             |distance(x, \sigma S)|, x \in S^c
             \end{array}  
\right.
$$
For example, SDF of sphere is $sdf(x) = ||x||_2 - 1$, sdf of octahedron is $sdf(x) = (||p||_1 - 1)/ sqrt(3)$.
My question is:
If I have a 3D sdf on 3D space, how could I project the sdf onto the 2D plane?
I know we can sample some points on sdf and project this points individually. But I want to transform the 3D sdf into 2D sdf directly.
Thanks!!!
=================================================================
The projection of sdf is not necessarily sdf, but it doesn't matter.
Thanks for reminding.

... knowing that in general, the sdf of the projection isn't the projection of the sdf...

I have suppressed tag "algebraic geometry" which is a completely different domain.

Thanks for your reply. " sdf of the projection isn't the projection of the sdf", can u provide some references? Thanks!!!!

In fact, I was doing a rendering, I want to represent any shape with sdf, and render the sdf directly

I have no reference but take plainly a cube and its sdf which is a cube and project them along a slant plane ; compare the hexagons : you will see that the innermost haxagon hasn't the outermost hexagon as its sdf.
